# Constrain a YUI Container in a DIV

Tags: javascript, html, yui

Is it possible to constrain a draggable YUI2 Container in a DIV instead of the whole page?

I know its possible using YUI3 Drag n Drop:
http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/examples/dd/constrained-drag_clean.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/dragdrop/dd-region.html Here is a link to the example of drag and drop in a bounded region.  It is part of the yui 2 drag and drop here http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/dragdrop/#using